# Issue generating Pact files using PactContractConverter

Tags: pact, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to generate the pact files as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779248/publish-spring-cloud-contract-verification-to-pact-broker) so I can verify the results to my broker.

Version: spring cloud 2.2.2 & Pact JVM 3.5.23. 
I've configured the plugin as shown below...

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>convert-dsl-to-pact</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                            <mainClass>org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ToFileContractsTransformer</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.spec.pact.PactContractConverter</argument>
                                <argument>${project.basedir}/target/pacts</argument>
                                <argument>${project.basedir}/target/generated-test-sources/contracts</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I get the following error...

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (convert-dsl-to-pact) @ employee ---
...
10:55:24.349 [org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ToFileContractsTransformer.main()] WARN org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter - Exception occurred while trying to parse the file [/Users/luke/workspaces/dbs/employee/employee-service/employee/target/generated-test-sources/contracts/com/backbase/dbs/employee/contract/com/backbase/dbs/employee/employee_serviceagreements_get_api_producer_pact/ContractsTest.java] as a contract. Will not parse it.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class with name [ContractsTest] not found
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.classConstructor(ContractVerifierDslConverter.groovy:166)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.parseJavaFile(ContractVerifierDslConverter.groovy:144)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.toObject(ContractVerifierDslConverter.groovy:131)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierDslConverter.convertAsCollection(ContractVerifierDslConverter.groovy:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractScanner$1.visitFile(ContractScanner.groovy:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractScanner$1.visitFile(ContractScanner.groovy)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractScanner.collectContractDescriptors(ContractScanner.groovy:77)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractScanner.collectContractDescriptors(ContractScanner.groovy:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ToFileContractsTransformer.storeContractsAsFiles(ToFileContractsTransformer.groovy:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ToFileContractsTransformer.main(ToFileContractsTransformer.groovy:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The generated sources and generated tests seem to be in the correct place. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please file an issue in the spring cloud contract repo